# Get alternate email addresses

Tags: vba, outlook, vsto, office-addins

I log in to Outlook on my home PC with an Office School/Work account (not a Microsoft Account). It looks similar to mjf@organization.com

The PrimarySMTP associated with this account is matt.fitzmaurice@organization.com
Which I can get programmatically via:

```
Application.Session.Accounts[1].CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
```

How can I programmatically get the Work account email address (mjf@organization.com)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might have been a silly question...

But in case anyone else needs to do this, the information is available as the userPrincipalName in MS Graph:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me

Answer (score 0):

You may check the [ExchangeUser.Alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.exchangeuser.alias) property which returns a string representing the alias for the `ExchangeUser`, for example:

```
Application.Session.Accounts[1].CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().Alias
```

Comment: Wasn't there unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

The alternative (called proxy) addresses are stored in the `PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES` (DASL name `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x800F101F"`) MAPI property. It is a multivalued (returned as an array) string property and can be accessed through `AddressEntry.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`. Each address will be prefixed with its type , e.g., `"EX:"`, `"smtp:"`, etc. The default SMTP address is prefixed with `"SMTP:"`.

Comment: Thanks, it returned 9 values, the default SMTP address is not the userPrincipalName in my case. The userPrincipalName is appearing as one of the other three prefixed with smtp: and also in one entry prefixed with SIP:

Comment: Problem is that I can't see any way of determining which of those 9 values is the userPrincipalName. So, I think I'll have to run off to MS Graph and get it.

Comment: BTW, is there a way of getting a list of all the various Properties? I was searching for PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES last week, but couldn't find it.

Comment: Sure - take a look at the address entries with OutlookSpy (https://www.dimastr.com/outspy - I am its author). For the GAL entries, you can open then by clicking IAddrBook | Open Container | Global Address List | GetContentsTable. Or click IMAPISession | QueryIdentity to look at the GAL entry representing the current user.

Comment: I was hoping that it was documented. Much as I know your software is good, I'd rather not install it on those occasions when I want this information (a handful of occasions in the last 20 years).